# SQL query using xp_cmdshell under select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Do u have any idea how can run windows commands under sql query with dbo privilege i am not able use exec directly is it possible with select maybe as second command to union maybe ?

I want to run basic windows commands like ipconfig, net user such as..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't execute any kind of procedure from a SELECT statement. You could use insert the results in a table and select from there.

Comment: Is it possible to insert first and select ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to insert the execution result of cmd shell into a Table, then you can make a select

```
declare @cmd as nvarchar(max)
--replace "dir c:\" by your cmd shell
set @cmd='exec master..xp_cmdshell "dir c:\"'
declare @mytab as table(id int identity(1,1),res nvarchar(200))
insert into @mytab exec(@cmd)

select * from @mytab
```

Comment: Thanks i actually want make it a bit trickier let's say i am at "cmd" already how can make this from windows command and write into sql server table dir c:\ is it possible ?

Comment: use sqlcmd https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-2017